# How to start the same timer which is stop in the past in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I am working on audio player in that timers are involved when play button clicked in audio player i wrote this code

```
- (IBAction)playButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    bookTitleString=[[selectBook titleLabel]text];
    startChapterString =[[startChapter titleLabel]text];
    NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:startChapterString ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:bookTitleString];
    NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:string isDirectory:YES];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    AVURLAsset *audioAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:url];
    CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
    audioDurationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
    NSLog(@"audioDurationInSeconds is %f",audioDurationInSeconds);

    slider.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = audioDurationInSeconds;
    slider.value = 0.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    if(audioPlayer == nil){
        NSLog(@"audio player is nil");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"audio player is not nil");
        NSLog(@"audioplayer.deviceCurrentTime is %f",audioPlayer.deviceCurrentTime);
        [audioPlayer play];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(sliderTintChanged:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}
```

in above i will take a timer as a class variable

after complete the playing of song it goes to AVAudioPlayerDelegate that is 
audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag

here the code for this audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    [timer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"song finished playing");
    NSString *startSongNumber = [[startChapter titleLabel]text];
    NSLog(@"startSongNumber is %@",startSongNumber);
    int songNumber = [startSongNumber intValue];
    NSLog(@"songNumber is %d",songNumber);
    songNumber = songNumber+1;
    NSLog(@"songNumber is %d",songNumber);
    NSString *nextSongNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",songNumber];
    NSLog(@"next song number is %@",nextSongNumber);
   NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:nextSongNumber ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:bookTitleString];
    NSLog(@"string is in playerdidfinish is %@",string);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:string isDirectory:YES];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    AVURLAsset *audioAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:url];
    CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
    audioDurationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
    NSLog(@"audioDurationInSeconds is %f",audioDurationInSeconds);
    [audioPlayer play];

}
```

here above at the starting i am invalidate the timer and then get the next song path and start play but i don't know how to start the timer which is stopped in above method

if any body know this please help me..

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Please accept some answers to your other questions, there's more info about how and why in [the SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like you did in playButtonClicked method...

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(sliderTintChanged:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

timer is generally use for time increment, it is in seconds.
in your method

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(sliderTintChanged) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

the timer call method after every one second.

```
-(void)sliderTintChanged
{
   //you can use a variable which will keep timer value
   //like this
   count++;
}
```

count is an integer variable assign int count=0;
when timer will be stopped count has the time in seconds and you can use it.

and NSTimer "fire date" keeps the fire detail in which time the method is call.
for more detail read fire date.